# Opencv: ValueError

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, opencv, contour

I have detected contours and stored them in cnts and i am accessing them one by one, c_list is the list of contours which are of interest to me.
I want to check if the contour i am accessing now is already been accessed before or not by using this code:

```
if not (np.all(cnts[c] in c_list)):
      while hierarchy[0][k][2] != -1:
        k = hierarchy[0][k][2]
        c_list.append(cnts[k])
        s = s+1
```

still i am getting error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Can someone please correct me what i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you post sample data for both `cnts` and `c_list`?

Comment: yeah sure, but its a big, very big list indeed, therefore i have uploaded it to google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQtERw_QqwEOEExTnZmMXFFWWs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: A couple of elements would be enough just to see their structure.

Comment: the complete contours and c_list which contains countours of interest are [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQtERw_QqwEOEExTnZmMXFFWWs/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: This is how c_list item look like

 array([[[291, 267]],
......,
       [[288, 268]],

       [[289, 267]]])]
    
    end of c_list items
    
    
    start of cnts
    
[array([[[590, 638]]]),........., array([[[638, 635]],

       [[635, 638]],

       [[636, 638]],

       [[638, 636]]])
    
    end of cnts

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your code? It's not clear why you are using `np.all()` here. A [mcve] would make it easier for others to help.

Comment: sure here it is

` (cnts, hierarchy) = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if(cnts):

        # checking for concentric condition
        for c in range(0,len(cnts)):
            k = c
            s=0
            #print hierarchy[0][k][2]
            #print str(c_list) + "this is list end\n"
            if not (np.all(cnts[c] in c_list)):
                 while hierarchy[0][k][2] != -1:
                    k = hierarchy[0][k][2]
                    c_list.append(cnts[k])
                    s = s+1
            print "s is " + str(s)`

Comment: This is in better formatting:

    `for c in range(0,len(cnts)):  
             k = c  
             s=0  
      if not (np.all(cnts[c] in c_list)):  
      while hierarchy[0][k][2] != -1:  
          k = hierarchy[0][k][2]  
          c_list.append(cnts[k])  
          s = s+1  
             print "s is " + str(s)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't add code in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not really related to OpenCV, it comes from numpy.

Consider the following examples:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [1,3] in [[1,3],[4,5]]
True

>>> np.array([1,3]) in [[1,3],[4,5]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

In comments you specified (what we could've asserted from OpenCV itself, but this information should have been in your question to begin with) that the objects you're comparing are *probably* something like

```
c_list = [[[[291, 267]], [[288, 268]], [[289, 267]]]]
cnts = np.array([[[291, 267]], [[288, 268]], [[289, 267]]])
# test for cnts[0] in c_list
```

The problem is that an indexed element of a `numpy.ndarray` is still a `numpy.ndarray`, but as you've seen with my first example, numpy arrays behave differently when you try to use the usual logical operations on them paired with native lists. This makes sense because in native python *the only obvious way* of handling `in` with list-valued operands is to test if the second list has a list-valued element equal to the first list. With numpy, you often want to do elementwise tests on your arrays, this is why the same expression leads to an error.

Now, fixing your problem is more complicated than one would expect. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, and there's probably a more logical way to do it. Anyway, consider these modified examples:

```
>>> [1,3] in [[1,3],[4,5]]
True
>>> [1,3] in [[1,2],[4,5]]
False
>>> np.array([1,3]) in np.array([[1,3],[4,5]])
True
>>> np.array([1,3]) in np.array([[1,2],[4,5]])
True
>>> np.array([1,3]) in np.array([[0,2],[4,5]])
False
```

While using `in` between *two ndarrays* doesn't produce an error, it behaves in a surprising way: it returns `True` if there are *any* common elements between the two arrays! This is obviously not what you want to do.

As I see it, you have two options. You can either convert all your ndarrays to lists. What I mean:

```
>>> np.array([1,3]).tolist() in np.array([[1,3],[4,5]]).tolist()
True
>>> np.array([1,3]).tolist() in np.array([[1,2],[4,5]]).tolist()
False
```

This would need for you to call `c_list.append(cnts[k].tolist())` and test `if not (cnts[c].tolist() in c_list):`, but it's usually not a very good idea to convert numpy arrays to native python lists, mainly due to memory considerations. If your contours have a lot of elements (which depends on whether you're passing `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` to `findContours()`), this might be a strong constraint.

The other option is to do it fully with numpy. If I understand correctly that you want to check if the array `np.array([[a,b]])` is in the list of arrays `[np.array([[c,d]]), np.array([[f,g]]),...]`, then you can use *elementwise* equality tests making use of array broadcasting, and using `np.all()` and `np.any()` to reduce the result. Example:

```
>>> to_find = np.array([[1,3]])
>>> in_which = [np.array([[2,4]]),np.array([[1,3]]),np.array([[5,6]])]
>>> to_find in in_which
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> np.all(to_find==in_which,axis=-1).any()
True
```

The same with a list that *doesn't* contain your template:

```
>>> to_find = np.array([[1,3]])
>>> in_which = [np.array([[2,4]]),np.array([[1,2]]),np.array([[5,6]])]
>>> np.all(to_find==in_which,axis=-1).any()
False
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment that's exactly i was looking for to find my contours in the contour list of interest.  :+1:

Actually the cnt_list is all the contours which are hierarchical, as i need those only, and cnts[c] is the one to check if his parent is already checked then skip this one just to improve the algo.

Comment: but i cant exactly compare the arrays in python list to the single np array can you please tell the how to do that please,
as changing the if condition to            ```python  if not (np.all(cnts[c] in c_list)).any(): ```
still throws throw same error, so how can i change the cnt_list to numpy array ?

Comment: @warl0ck how about doing what I wrote in my answer? Look at the last code block and try to see if it can be applied to your problem.

Comment: problem is in_which variable you are specifying the numpy arrays but i already have them in list and its not checking in list and throwing same error.

Comment: will it be same as using or is there any more efficient way 

**` any(cnts[c] is c for c in cnt_list)`** 

i found this in one of solutions on stack itself

Comment: @warl0ck My `in_which` is a list of numpy arrays. Which is exactly what your `c_list` should be according to your code. So, again: have you tried what I wrote, `np.all(cnts[c]==cnt_list,axis=-1).any()`?

Comment: Of course, `np.all()` (edited my previous comment). Please try to fully read answers you are given, it's quicker that way.

Comment: sure and thanks a lot for this descriptive answer,
 also it might look that i didn't read but i actually did just because i forgot that axis=-1 thats why my bad